# How do I iterate through a python DICT to extract a specific value of a specific key?

Tags: python

I have the following dict shown below that was created from a GET request.  I want to be iterate through this dict to extract all the user emails only.  I dont want the key with the value, just a new list of email addresses.  How can I most efficiently loop through a long dict and pull out just the value of the key 'email'?  I have tried using the json.load() fucntion, but run into problems with the data type.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1262635064750,
            "url": "https://xxxx.xxx.com/api/v2/users/1262635064xxx.json",
            "name": "Customer A",
            "email": "customerA@example.com",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:12Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:15Z",
            "time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "iana_time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "phone": null,
            "shared_phone_number": null
         }
 {
            "id": 1262635064751,
            "url": "https://xxxx.xxx.com/api/v2/users/1262635064xxx.json",
            "name": "Customer B",
            "email": "customerB@example.com",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:12Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:15Z",
            "time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "iana_time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "phone": null,
            "shared_phone_number": null
         }
 {
            "id": 1262635064752A,
            "url": "https://xxxx.xxx.com/api/v2/users/1262635064xxx.json",
            "name": "Customer C",
            "email": "customerC@example.com",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:12Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-05T22:05:15Z",
            "time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "iana_time_zone": "America/Chicago",
            "phone": null,
            "shared_phone_number": null
         }
```

Comment: If you have a dictionary, you do not need to, or should not, use `json.loads`.

Comment: However, what you have shown is neither a Python dictionary, nor JSON.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Iterating through basic data structures is covered quite well in any tutorial on that data structure.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
emails = [user["email"] for user in response["users"]]
```

This assumes that your top-level dictionary is stored as a variable named `response`. Then `response["users"]` is a list of dictionaries. This list comprehension loops over this list, assigning each user dictionary to `user` and accessing its value for the `"email"` key.

Comment: Of course, the 'dict' is full of syntax errors, as @mkreiger1 comments above:

Comment: The 'null's should be 'None', quotes around the "id" vals, commas delimiting the inner dicts, closing square and curly brackets.  So, if that is what you are getting out of your request.args.get, then you need to fix the client code as well as do some cleanup on your route processing.